# Using pointer destination in strftime (C)

Tags: c, string, time

First, the apology: new to C, and fairly green in coding generally.

The problem: trying to create a timestamp in C using strftime().
This works:

```
    #include <time.h>
    ...
    char timestamp[14];
    ...[code to define timestruct]
    strftime(timestamp,15,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S", timestruct);
```

But **this** gives a segmentation fault:

```
    #include <time.h>
    ...
    char *timestamp;
    ...[code to define timestruct]
    strftime(timestamp,15,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S", timestruct);
```

Obviously, I have a solution that works, so basically all is well. But why does the version with `timestamp` as a pointer not work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try mallocing the timestamp in the second case first. That is, do `char *timestamp = malloc(14)`.

Comment: What is the _value_ of the pointer `timestamp` in the 2nd case when `strftime(timestamp,15,...` is called?

Comment: @gowrath Got it, thank you.

Comment: @chux eg "20160909204853" plus presumably a terminating `\0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers in C require you to allocate space for them on the heap. In the first case, when you declare `char timestamp[14]`, the 14 in the brackets is telling the compiler to allocate 14 bytes on the stack for timestamp. So you can use it for strings shorted than 14 bytes and you'll be fine.

In the second case, you declare `char *timestamp` but don't allocate any memory to it. Thus when `strftime` tries to write to it, it is writing to invalid memory that it doesn't have access to so you get a seg fault. To fix this, you need to allocate memory to timestamp by saying `char *timestamp = malloc(14)`. This will point timestamp to 14 bytes allocated on the heap that it can use. The issue with this method is you have to free the memory manually by calling `free(timestamp)` after you are done using it.

The first method is preferred if `timestamp` is a local variable that doesn't need to exist longer than the scope of the function it is in because it will automatically get cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

because in the second example `timestamp` is an unitialized pointer: segv when `strftime` is writing to it.

If you want to use a pointer, allocate the memory using `malloc`

```
char *timestamp = malloc(20);  // 20 is maybe too much, better safe than sorry
```

If you want to use `timestamp` locally and not return it to a caller, I would recommend the first solution, as it does not involve allocation/deallocation. Faster and safer (no possible memory leaks)

Answer (score 0):

`strftime()` needs a buffer in `timestamp` to write the formatted string into. It doesn't allocate memory for that buffer itself. When you use `char timestamp[14]` you have a 14-character buffer and things are almost OK, you should send 14 for the `max` argument instead of 15 to avoid writing past the end of `timestamp`. When you're using `char *timestamp` though there's just a pointer containing a random value but no memory's allocated. `strftime()` is going to dereference that random pointer and try to write to wherever in memory it refers to, and what happens then depends on where that memory is. If it's nonexistent or inaccessible you'll get a segmentation fault, if it happens to exist and be writable it'll appear to work but in reality you'll have just corrupted something unknown somewhere else which may cause random bugs to pop up later on. If you want to use a `char *` instead of an array of char for `timestamp` you'll need to also use `malloc()` or similar to allocate memory and assign the result to `timestamp` so it points to allocated memory before calling `strftime()`.

Answer (score 0):

Both tests cause undefined behavior (UB).

1. The first mis-led `strftime()` by telling it the buffer size was one larger that it was.  Writing outside the buffer is UB.  OP reports it "works", but that is one possibility of UB.  It is bad code and should be re-written

   ```
   char timestamp[14];
   //                  v
   strftime(timestamp,15,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S", timestruct);

   // Use this instead

   char timestamp[15 /* or more */];
   strftime(timestamp, sizeof timestamp,"%Y%m%d%H%M%S", timestruct);
   ```
2. The 2nd apparently does not give `timestamp` a value  so undefined data it passed to `strftime()` telling it to with *somewhere*.  This is UB as `timestamp` has an undefined value.   It is bad code and should be re-written to allocate memory first.

   ```
   char *timestamp;
   ...
   strftime(timestamp, 15, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", timestruct);

   // Use this instead

   #define timestamp_N 15
   {
   char *timestamp = malloc(timestamp_N);
   assert(timestamp);  //  Check allocation
   ...
   strftime(timestamp, timestamp_N, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", timestruct);
   ... // Use timestamp
   free(timestamp);
   }
   ```

---

Further: 1) The year field (+ 1900) is not limited to 0000 to 9999. 15 is insufficient for robust use of `"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"`. 2) There is little need to be so stingy with the buffer size. Suggest a buffer size like  32 that can cope with a 64-bit `tm_year` field.  3) Result does not indicate timezone.  Append a  `Z` for UTC.  4) Review standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).